# Turn Perl variable into regex

Tags: regex, perl, hash

Here I have

```
my %id_to_name = (
    51803 => 'Jim bob and associates',
);

while (my ($key, $value) = each %id_to_name) {
    $regex = qr/^.*?$value.*?$/;
    $value = $regex;
```

I basically want to match `$value` to:

```
a bunch of random text blah blah 'Jim bob and associates' blah blah.
```

I can't seem to get a match because of all the text before and after.

I am trying `qr//` but it does not seem to work. Any suggestions?

Comment: perhaps `=~` instead of `=`?

Comment: What exactly *"does not seem to work"*? What do you expect your code to do? You probably want `my $regex = qr/\Q$value/`. There is no point at all in the leading and trailing `.*?`.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you don't need regex for that... The [`index`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/index.html) function will let you check if a string contains a substring.

```
print $value if index($input, $value) >= 0;
```

FYI, a regex solution would be:

```
print $value if $input =~ m/\Q$value\E/;
```

You can use it if you need modifiers (like `i` for a case insensitive match). `\Q...\E` is like [`quotemeta`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/quotemeta.html).

Answer (score 0):

On Perl 5.18.2, this works:

```
my %id_to_name = (
    51803  =>  'Jim bob and associates',
            );

while (my ($key, $value) = each %id_to_name) {
    $regex = qr/^.*?$value.*?$/;
    print "$regex\n";
    $test="a bunch of random text blah blah 'Jim bob and associates' blah blah.";
    print "match" if $test =~/$value/;
}
```

Prints:

```
(?^:^.*?Jim bob and associates.*?$)
match
```

As stated in comments, the leading and trailing `.*?` are pointless.